# newQuad function limited to 5? Lua

Tags: lua, tile, love2d

I use Love2D with lua and when i use 5 quads (love.graphics.newQuad) It seems to work just fine, but when i use 6 quads there shows a weird error:

```
Error menu.lua:9: Incoorect parameter type: expected userdata.
Traceback [C]: in function 'drawq'
menu.lua:9: in function 'draw'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Menu line 9 is this:

```
love.graphics.drawq(Tileset, Quads[number], x, y)
```

I assume it has something to do with the quads cause when i delete the sixth one from the tile map and the 6th quad it will load.

I tried to copy the other quads to see if i miss spelld something, but this is not the case.

Here is the code:

[menu.lua](http://xedus.nl/test_builds/menu.lua)

[main.lua](http://xedus.nl/test_builds/main.lua)

[mapsload.lua](http://xedus.nl/test_builds/mapsload.lua)

Comment: Put the code in your actual post. At least the Lua code. Don't make people download some zip file.

Comment: I meant in your post, not providing links to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only defining 5 entries in the `Quads` table in your `main.lua`. If you look closely at `mapsload.lua` at `MenuBack` row 17, you will see the value **6** standing lonely among 1-5.

Now when want to use `Quads[6]`, that key is not in the table `Quads`. Therefore Lua returns **nil**. And as you can guess, **nil** is not **userdata**, that is why the function `drawq` fails.